CSS not loading in Onion share
I created a React app with a Spring Boot backend hosted on Netlify, and it was working fine. However, when I built and deployed it on OnionShare, I encountered the following issues:
The CSS is not rendering.
The REST call is returning an error.
I tried installing the No CORS plugin and disabling private browsing as suggested by many, but the issue persists.

Ensure that the package.json is correctly configured with OnionShare and also the environment variables are proper. For Spring Boot ensure that the build version is proper.
